# Vertical-aligned navigation using display: table

Tags: css, navigation, vertical-alignment

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/M4Jfd/) showing the styling I have, (making use of `display: table` as I don't want to fix the width of each item and it should be responsive).

I'm close, here's the styling (SASS for brevity) and how it looks:

```
.nav--main {
    ul {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        li {
            display: table-cell;
            border: 1px solid #333;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 1.2;
            vertical-align: top;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    }
    a {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200%;
        padding: .5em;
        background-color: rgba(105,158,197,1);
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```

But I cannot get the `a` to take up the full height and remain vertically-centered in the middle. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/hV9t6/) shows one kinda hacky attempt, but only by setting `vertical-align` to `top`.

[image]

I don't want to:

- set a fixed height
- place the background-color on the `li` rather than the `a`: I hate when the clickable area doesn't take advantage of all available space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, in which case this might break, but a somewhat dirty trick could be this:

**Updated CSS parts only**

```
ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}

a {
    margin: -5em 0;
    padding: 5.5em 0;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/xTGtK/)

Comment: Cheers - that actually seems to work pretty well (in Chrome, FF and IE 8-10). Would like to see if anyone can come up with a less 'dirty' solution! This also makes it hard, e.g., to add a gradient background on the link as much of it is actually hidden.

Comment: I guess there's no other way, except using a small JavaScript. The [CSS2.1 specifications "17.5.3 Table height algorithms"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#height-layout) say: "*In CSS 2.1, **the height of a cell box is the minimum height required by the content**. The table cell's 'height' property can influence the height of the row (see above), but it does not increase the height of the cell box.*".

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
background: rgba(105,158,197,1);
```

into `ul`

That set the background color into the same as your link.

Comment: This doesn't solve it, as the OP wants the link to fill up the entire table cell.

Comment: @insertusernamehere then I think it is impossible based on his requirements, without changing the height of link or width.